# Finding a reduction for two-Subset sum problem

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

I'd like to prove that the following problem is NP-complete. I'd just like to know what reduction I should do:

*Two Subset Sum: Given a set S of integers and an integer T, determine whether there are two subsets of S such that the sum of the numbers of one is T and the other is 2T. The subsets do NOT have to be disjoint.*

And I want to use the classic subset problem to prove this:

*Subset Sum: Given a set S of integers and an integer T, determine whether there is a subset of S such that the sum of the numbers is T.*

I'm slightly struggling with the reduction from Subset-Sum to 2-Subset-Sum, as simply adding to the set the double of each number and using the same T does not work, e.g `S = {1,7,8,5}` and `S'={1,2,5,10,7,8,14,16}` with `T = 10` wouldn't work, as S' would return "true" and S should return "false".

Thank you.

Comment: Try reducing from the PARTITION problem instead of general SUBSET-SUM.

Comment: It might be easier with the Partition problem, but I specifically want from Subset-Sum (It's part of the question's requirement).

Comment: In that case, you can compose the reduction from Subset-Sum to Partition and the reduction from Partition to your problem. Both are pretty simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have an idea how to do the reduction directly though? It's definitely possible.

Comment: Think about how you could reduce a problem in which you are given a set $S$ of integers and an integer $T$, and need to determine whether some subset of $S$ sums to $T$, to the same problem, but with $T$ forced to be 0.  When constructing the instance of the second problem, think about what effect multiplying all numbers, or adding a constant to each number, has on its solutions.

Comment: It is definitely possible to do the reduction directly. You simply compose the two reductions I mentioned, and state them as a single reduction. Since the reduction from Partition to your problem doesn't even require changing the instance (the $S$ part), this won't be much more difficult than just reducing Subset-Sum to Partition.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trivial reduction from Partition to your problem: given an instance $S$ of partition, construct the instance $(S,\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in S} i)$ of your problem. This shows that if you take any reduction from Subset-Sum to Partition, you immediately get a reduction from Subset-Sum to your problem. You can find the reduction from Subset-Sum to Partition in many places, or come up with it on your own.